# How do you add dragon souls?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Using the console in Skyrim, how do you add dragon souls? I tried `player.adddragonsouls`, similar to `player.additem` or `player.addperk` but it did not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

> player.modav dragonsouls #

OR

> player.forceav dragonsouls #

to add souls.

Modav adds a number of souls to your total, forceav sets the number of souls to the chosen number.

Complete list of console commands [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29).

Comment: I think modav would be better, forceav can introduce problems.

Comment: @One-One modav adds to or subtracts from a value, forceav sets it. You can read more at shan's link.