# Console command for perk points

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Instead of going through the player.advskill loop, I've been wondering if there is a command to get me a set number of perk points directly.

Does such a command exist?

(In case of confusion, by perk points I mean the points you spend to level perks up, not skills.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no console command that allows you to change how many perk points you have. You either need to give yourself perks directly, as in [Kaizerwolf's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/290750), or use a mod to adjust your perk points.

If you have the [Deadly Dragons](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/3829/?) mod, you can [give yourself dragon souls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/121881) in the console, and then use the mod to convert them to perk points. If you want two more perk points, give yourself ten dragon souls with `player.modav dragonsouls 10`, and then use the Deadly Dragons mod configuration menu to convert the souls to perk points (if you kept the default conversion rate of 5 dragon souls per perk point).

There might be other mods that make the process more convenient, but Deadly Dragons is the only one I've used.

Comment: I actually have that mod, but I never realized I could do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Aside from `advlevel`, which would increase your level by 1 (but not add any perk points), I don't see any commands to give yourself a set amount of perk points.

On the upside, however, is this: `addperk <perk ID>`. By specifying the perk ID, which can be found online, you can just give yourself the perks you want. [As the UESP's example goes](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console), you would type the following into the console:

```
player.addperk 000c44c0
```

and it would give you the Adept Destruction perk.

Comment: The command you mention is "advlevel" not "adlevel". It's shorthand for AdvancePCLevel. It also does *not* give a perk point.

Comment: @TylerShellberg lil typo, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
player.setlevel 1

advskill (enter any skill here) 99999999999
```

(example `advskill block 999999999`)

Make skill legendary

Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Important note: the number after advskill is the amount of XP gained, not the number of levels.

Answer (score -2):

So today I learned that if you use console command (using sneak as example)
1.Player.setav sneak 100
2.Exit command screen then open again
3.Player.Setav sneak 0
4.Exit command screen and crouch until hidden. Your sneak skill will advance to 100. Go to skills menu, accept level advancement points (you can spend perk points now or do it later) open command screen again.
Repeat steps 3 and 4 as many times as you want to gain more perk points.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

If you have ordinator you could use vemonus's method until you get dragon hoard, from the pickpocket skill tree. Cheat some gold in and then go to a house or and in and spam sleep and ok

Hope it helpes
:)